# How can I format my Stream Writer to write to my text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, stream

The text file is being used to describe the state of the game on a web browser. So I need to format my nameWriter.WriteLine to look something like.

```
Output to text file:
playerOneName, playerTwoName, _ , _ , _ , _ , _ , _ , _ , _
```

I know this may sound like "Oh just writeLine this!" But no, the underscores are an empty field that are to be replace by my StreamWriter, it tracks the moves of the player in a tic tac toe web game. What can I use instead of the underscore to make that space available for my read and write?

Here is my StreamWriter, right now I only have it adding the player name.

#### Can you show me how to format the output to text?

Maybe separate it in an array? and use a array DelimiterList to key out the commas?

```
    string[] lineParts... and reference the linePart[0-11] 
and then do a lineParts = line.Split(delimiterList)?
```

Here is my write code.

```
private void WriteGame(string playerOneName, string playerTwoName, string[] cells)
    {
        StreamWriter gameStateWriter = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            gameStateWriter = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);
            gameStateWriter.WriteLine(playerOneName + " , " + playerTwoName);
            string[] gameState = { playerOneName, 
            playerTwoName, null, null, null, null, 
    null, null, null, null, null };//I cannot use null, they will give me errors
            foreach (string GameState in gameState)
            {
                sb.Append(GameState);
                sb.Append(",");
            }
            gameStateWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtOutcome.Text = "The following problem ocurred when writing to the file:\n"
               + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (gameStateWriter != null)
                gameStateWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Lastly if playerOneName is already in the text file, how do I specifically write playerTwoName after it and check that it is there?**

Using Visual Studio '08 ASP.NET website and forms

Comment: Just FYI: your streamwriter should be in a `using` block. It will take care of disposing the stream at the end of its scope.

Comment: Also, why does your website need to create a text file to store information?

Comment: The text file is the server file, I am practicing how to Read and write to file on a server to a browser. For every move a player makes in the 9 buttons a tic tac toe game has, it is recorded in the server text file which is shared by player two. So they are playing the same game on the same file. But there can be multiple games going on. Which means I need to use different lines to track each game's progression.

Comment: Yes there are a number of other problems with the code (why is game state a set of strings rather than an object? that's the biggest question).

Comment: Truth is, I'm doing a 3 man project, and my peers are unhelpful. Heck if I know what is really suppose to go there. Just by trial and error is how I can bash out this project, if you have any advice I'd love to hear it. Both players share the file, and an array will give me 11 placements. 2 for the players playing, and 9 for the amount of buttons on the tic tac toe field. So if they press button 5, the 5th field after my player names becomes an "X". So when checking for winner, I'm looking for different combinations in that array to find winner.

Comment: @GivenPie A text file is entirely the wrong way to be storing your game data. A database would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, define the fact that underscore is a special thing that means empty for you, and that commas are your delimiter:

```
const string EMPTY = "_";
const string DELIMITER = ",";
```

Secondly, don't write spaces between the comma and the values, that will just make your life more difficult later on:

```
// removed spaces
gameStateWriter.WriteLine(playerOneName + DELIMITER + playerTwoName);
```

Now your GameState is ready to be created:

```
string[] gameState = { playerOneName, playerTwoName, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, 
                       EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY,  };
```

To check if player two is already there, you need to open and read the existing file, and check to see if the second token is not empty. That is, if you've read the file;

```
var line = "..."; // read the file until the line that .StartsWith(playerOne)
var playerTwo = line.Split(DELIMITER)[1];

if (playerTwo == EMPTY)
{
     // need to store the real playerTwo, otherwise leave as is
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you broke it down for me really nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your code, but instead of `sb.Append(GameState);` do `sb.Append(GameState??"_");` in your current code.

"??" is [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) in C# - so result of `null ?? "_"` is "_" and `"SomeValue"??"_"` is "SomeValue".

Comment: That's very cool, thanks for showing me that, I will remember that for when I need define a null-able variable with a default. For my, this "_" null needs to be written by my StreamWriter to either X or O. Would it work if I set default to X, so I only need to take care of the player two's symbol.