# How to check and write to different lineparts using Stream Writer

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, stream

I am trying to write to a specific line part using Stream Writer, here's what I have so far:

#### The exception message is giving me: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
private void WriteData(string playerName)
    {
        StreamWriter nameWriter = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            string line = "";
            string namePartOne = line.Split(DELIMITER)[0];
            string namePartTwo = line.Split(DELIMITER)[1];
            if (namePartOne != EMPTY)
            {
                namePartTwo = playerName;
                string[] gameState = { namePartOne, namePartTwo, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY };
                sb.Append(gameState);
                nameWriter.WriteLine(String.Join(",", gameState));
            }
            else
            {
                nameWriter = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);
                string[] gameState = { playerName, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY };
               
                nameWriter.WriteLine(String.Join(",", gameState));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtTextBox2.Text = "The following problem ocurred when writing to the file:\n"
               + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Closing the StreamWriter should close it 
            // AND its underlying FileStream
            if (nameWriter != null)
                nameWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to out put this to my text file:

```
playerOneName, playerTwoName, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY
```

Basically this writer is used to write player one's from his browser, and player two's name from another browser/tab. I first want to check if player one's name is written in the first field, if it is, I will write then second player in the second field. The other field are left empty to describe the game state when the game is run.

I might have logic problems, please point out if you see any. Can I use regular expression to compare and validate my players are there?

I need to Stream Read this file before I can Stream Write the file, is that correct?

I am running Visual Studio '08 using APS.NET website and forms.

### Thanks for your time

Comment: wasn't this something I've seen yesterday? why don't refer to that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149250/how-can-i-format-my-stream-writer-to-write-to-my-text-file/10149601#comment13017225_10149601

Comment: its work in progress, new error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string line = "";
string namePartOne = line.Split(DELIMITER)[0];
string namePartTwo = line.Split(DELIMITER)[1];
```

this will result in the index out of bounds error, as you are splitting an empty string (which will return one item) and then trying to access the second item of that one-item list.

Also, might I suggest rather than using a StringBuilder, just do

```
String.Join(",", gameState);
```

to create your output string.

Here's a possible overall solution (apologies for any errors, as I don't have a compiler to hand):

```
List<String> gameState;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    gameState = reader.ReadLine().Split(new[] {','});

if (gameState[0] == "")
    gameState[0] = playerName
else
    gameState[1] = playerName;

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
    writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", gameState));
```

Note: 'using' is a handy way to get that try/finally which closes the stream for free (you'll still have to catch exceptions though).

Comment: the commas will only appear between items, not at the beginning or end

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can still split the the line up with delimiters but without using an empty string?

Comment: I'm not sure which line you are referring too.  If you mean gameState, that is already in an array.  You can check gameState[0] == "" and if that's false put the name in gameState[1], does that do what you want?